# Encoding for ä ü ö ß etc

Tags: python, utf-8, nlp, nltk

I have a list of strings, some of which contain letters such as  ä ü ö or ß. Tring to print them results in strings such as NatÃ¼rlichÂ or BedrÃ¼ckung. As suggested in other threads, I attempted solving the problem by going

```
str(word).encode("latin-1").decode("utf-8")
```

however, now I receive strings like this: Verkehrsl\xc3\x83\xc2\xa4rm, Windb\xc3\x83\xc2\xb6, Gro\xc3\x83\xc5\xb8stadt

The values were scraped from a book using spacy and nlp.

Comment: Are you using python 2.x or python 3.x? You can run `python --version` if you're not sure.

Comment: i am using python3

Comment: i dont mind which version I use just to resolve this problem

Comment: The output looks like you did `.encode('utf8').decode('latin-1')` (ie. the wrong way round).

Comment: When printing, you always have the potential issue that your command-line tool or IDE messes up the correctly encoded output of Python. Does it look alright if you write it to a file? (If you're on Windows, I suggest using "utf-8-sig" as output encoding.)

Comment: Especially on windows, console output on systems with versions older than 10 (7,8,8.1) don't provide unicode output at all. So print to a file, open with a text editor and check your encoding again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string like `NatÃ¼rlich` then the approach from your question should work:

```
raw = 'NatÃ¼rlich'
converted = raw.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
print(converted)
```

This prints `Natürlich`.

Note that `NatÃ¼rlichÂ` as given in the question is problematic because the trailing `Â` character is only half of a Unicode representation of something (like the `Ã¼` pair earlier in the word). This causes a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

If you're feeling brave, you can tell the decoder to ignore such errors:

```
raw = 'NatÃ¼rlichÃ'
converted = raw.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
print(converted)
```

--

These encoding problems are common enough that a library has been written to try to automatically detect and fix these encoding problems: [ftfy](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy). If you `pip install ftfy` then you should simply be able to do this:

```
import ftfy
raw = 'NatÃ¼rlich'
fixed = ftfy.fix_text(raw)
print(fixed)
```

or you can explore what it's doing:

```
print(ftfy.fixes.fix_one_step_and_explain(raw))
```

which, in the case of your examples suggested the encode Latin 1, decode UTF-8 you were trying.

Comment: This answer helped solved a different problem for me using `open(csv_file, encoding='latin-1')`. I was able to avoid `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte` problem.